# How do I convert a ResultSet in a List of Hashtable?

Tags: java, sql

Well, that must be an easy one but I can't find the solution anywhere. And I am still not enough comfortable using Java to figure out the way to do it.

So far, I am able to loop through a `ResultSet` and I'm quite proud of myself already.

I would like a List so I could simply loop through it and then call something like `myRow.get('ColumnName');`.

Also, there MIGHT another data type instead of a `Hashtable` to store the key/value. Any tips?

Thank you very much!

Comment: you may consider HashMap, which stores values in key/value pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myRow.get('ColumnName');` is already in `ResultSet`, see [getObject(String columnLabel)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject%28java.lang.String%29). Now, one difference between `ResultSet` and `Map` is that a `ResultSet` is not (always) *random access*. Once you go past a row, using `ResultSet.next()`, it may not allow you to "rewind" to the previous row. There is good reason for this: the number of elements in ReusltSet can be arbitrarily large and the memory requirement on a list of map would be prohibitive.

If you do decide to convert it to a `List<Map<String, Object>>` then you should create your own implementation of both the `List` and the `Map`, such that a `Map<String /*columnName*/, Integer /*Index*/>` is gives the index of a column-name in each array. I am speaking from experience, I had to change an implementation where a iterating through list of column names was too expensive.

Comment: You are right. I could call the get method from the ResultSet directly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `HashMap`. `Hashtable` is old school...

Example:

```
HashMap<String, Object> p = new HashMap<String, Object>();
p.put("ResultSetkey1","ResultSetvalue1");
p.put("ResultSetkey2","ResultSetvalue2");
```

Answer (score 0):

what I understand it would be something like this:

```
LinkedList<HashTable<String,String>> list = new LinkedList<>();


while(rs.next()){
    Hashtable<String, String> currentRowMap = new Hashtable<>();

    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        // retrieves column name and value.
        String key = rsmd.getColumnLabel(i);
        String value = rs.getString(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
        if (value == null) {
            value = "null";
        }
        // builds map.
        currentRowMap .put(key, value);
    }
    list.add(currentRowMap);
}

return list;
```