# Datatable to Multidimensional Array

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable, asp.net-4.0

Is there an easy way to convert a Datatable to a multidimensional string array?

Maybe using `LINQ`?

There's gotta be a better way than manually looping through all the columns/rows...

Comment: There is a good reason for looping, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918157/how-do-i-convert-a-resultset-in-a-list-of-hashtable/8918431#8918431

Comment: don't you think you will loop over all the records during conversion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Linq is the answer. You can convert a `DataTable` to IEnumerable using the `AsEnumerable` method. Then, the `ToArray()` converts it to an array.

```
var tableEnumerable = DataTableName.AsEnumerable();
tableArray = tableEnumerable.ToArray();
```

Comment: sorry, I've never used LINQ before. I'm getting this error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataRow[]' to 'string[*,*]'` Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you getting that error on the line I gave you?
If so, can you break it into different parts (enumerable = DataTable.asenumerable(); tablearray = enumerable.toarray();) and see if it still react the same.

Comment: @Greg I am getting the same error, even with this split up over multiple lines. Did you ever get it resolved?

Comment: @Rachel yep, try something like this `var foo = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ItemArray).ToArray();`

Answer (score 4):

yourTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.ItemArray).ToArray()

Answer (score 0):

try
dt.Rows.Cast().Select(//datarow to strings)