# Convert DataTable into object[ , ] array with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I sincerely apologize if this has been asked before; maybe I am just blind and not finding it.  Is it possible to convert a DataTable into an object[ , ] type array using LINQ?  Using the following code I can convert it into object[][] but that's not what I need unfortunately:

```
object[][] tableEnumerable = dtReportData.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ItemArray).ToArray();
```

What I need is:

```
object [,] = ....?
```

Thank you in advance for any help and again, I apologize if this is a duplicate post.

EDIT:
I do not want object[][] as the posted solution is referring to, I need object[,]. At least learn to read people before you start subtracting points.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Datatable to Multidimensional Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932900/datatable-to-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Right, I actually looked at that but that will net me object[][] instead of object[,]  Thank you for the suggestion however.

Comment: Linq cannot create a rectangular array - you'll need to use nested `for` loops.

Comment: Thank you Stanley.  I opted for LINQ due to one-line code and hopefully a faster conversion time, but if it can't be done, then perhaps it's no wonder that I could not find such an answer.

Comment: Linq is just a shorter _syntax_ for normal loops - you usually don't see any  performance benefit.  In fact, there's usually a _very slight_ performance hit due to the overhead it has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use Linq to create a rectangular array - Linq only operates on single-dimension arrays.  You will need to use traditional `for` loops:

```
object[,] objectArray = new object[dtReportData.Rows.Count,
                                   dataTable1.Columns.Count];

for(int row = 0; row < dtReportData.Rows.Count; row++)
{
  for(int col = 0; col < dtReportData.Columns.Count; col++)
  {
    objectArray[row, col] = dtReportData.Rows[row][col];
  }
}
```

You *could* make this an extension method of `DataTable` to make the syntax cleaner if you like:

```
object[][] tableEnumerable = dtReportData.ToRectangularArray()
```

The extension method would be something like:

```
public static class MyDataTableExtensions
{
   public static object[,] ToRectangularArray(this DataTable dt)
   {
       // code above goes here
   }
}
```

Comment: So it can't be done with LINQ alone, fair enough.  I'll mark this as an answer since there is a work around provided.  Thank you!