# I'm trying to populate a multidimensional array from a datatable with no success

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to add data to a multidimensional array but keep getting the error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Object[][]' to 'string[*,*]'". Dunno how to fix this. I found this on SO but their solution didn't help me: [Datatable to Multidimensional Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932900/datatable-to-multidimensional-array)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
clDataTable = i_dbExec.ExecSelect(i_strQuery);
var tableEnumerable = clDataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => 
row.ItemArray).ToArray();
string[,] o_astrLocationCodes = tableEnumerable.ToArray(); <-- Error here
```

Comment: Why don't you use `var o_astrLocationCodes` and iterate that?

Comment: 1. `tableEnumerable` should already be an `Array` - you have `ToArray()` on the expression that initializes it. 2. Multidimensional arrays are not useful except in certain specific (normally mathematical) circumstances - why do you think it would be preferable to the `object[][]` `Array` you already have? 3. apparently the type of `.ItemArray` is `object[]` so it won't convert to `string[]` unless you convert each element.

Comment: Op, expand a bit more on what you're trying to accomplish. There is likely a better approach to take. But, it is possible to do what you want, no matter how non-proper it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ugly, and I don't know why you would do it this way, but I don't judge.

```
string[][] stringArray = 
    clDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(
        row => row.ItemArray
        .Select(
            i=>i.ToString()
        ).ToArray()
    ).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Cory and @NetMage for your answers. I thought I was constrained to providing an existing function (that I wasn't allowed to edit) with a multidimensional array, hence my question. But, I managed to find another workaround that didn't need the array. I'll mark Cory's answer as a solution since I could have used that in spite of his reservations... :)