# Is there a way of writing large datatable in an excel file more efficiently or faster?

Tags: c#, excel, csv, datatable, console-application

I'm quite new in handling huge data sets and I'm using C# for this. Now, the data that I'm handling (which is a CSV) has a column of 19 and row of 9,831. When it comes to writing the data into an existing excel file the program take 6 minutes to accomplish its task. I'm looking for suggestions or tips that can reduce the time rendering into seconds. So here's my class or code for writing it to an excel file:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Project
{
    class WriteCsv
    {
        public WriteCsv(DataTable dt)
        {
            //sets the existing excel file to be written
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook sheet = excel.Workbooks.Open(@"path to excel file");
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet x = excel.ActiveSheet as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;

            //selects a specific worksheet to written on
            x = (Excel.Worksheet)sheet.Sheets[2];

            int rowCount = 1; 
            int dataColumns = dt.Columns.Count;

            //this is where the writing starts
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                int columnCount = 0;
                while (columnCount < dataColumns)
                {
                    x.Cells[rowCount, columnCount + 1] = dr[columnCount];
                    columnCount++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("=====================ROW COMPLETED " + rowCount + "========================");
                rowCount++;

            }
            sheet.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            excel.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of the while loop?

Comment: @BaileyKocin OP is looping through each field in their `datarow` and writing it to the corresponding cell. Cell by painful cell.

Comment: It's for putting the data in specific cell of the excel file and for indicating what data should be written in that cell for the data row.

Comment: @JNevill I saw that! I just wanted to know why honestly...

Comment: @BaileyKocin Perhaps that's the help that OP is looking for?

Comment: Well, honestly I'm just a newbie so I go for the helpful codes that I can understand. So, any suggestion or changes that I can make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've dealt with this a few ways in the past. Especially when consuming a DataReader from a SQL source which is always a few hops, skips, and jumps from playing nice and fast with Excel.

Excel really likes 2-dim arrays though. What I've done with the `DataTable` in the past is converted it to a 2-dim array and then just dump that array into the spreadsheet all at once. You are still iterating through every row/column in the `DataTable`, but C# is fast about that.

```
        string[,] data = new string[dt.Rows.Count, dt.Columns.Count];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            int j = 0;
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                data[i,j++] = row[col].ToString();
            }
            i++;
        }

        //dump the whole array to the range
        x.Value = data
```

There's some other crafty ways of doing this by writing to a file with comma delimited rows (although I would use tab to make it more excel friendly), then opening the file, but that seems even more cumbersome. [Check out some interesting answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207869/how-to-export-datatable-to-excel)

You may also have some luck [converting that datatable to an array using `Linq`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932900/datatable-to-multidimensional-array), although I haven't tried yet.

Perhaps something like:

```
x.Value = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.ItemArray).ToArray()
```

I'm not convinced that's 100%, but it may be a step in the right direction.