# C# Multidimensional Array to DataTable

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, multidimensional-array, datatable

I have written a program wherein I fetch a data from an API and the built in API Parser stores the data retrieved in Multi-dimensional array format. I am converting the Multi-dimensional array into DataTable using the codes below:

```
for (i = mdArray.GetLowerBound(0); i <= mdArray.GetUpperBound(0); ++i)
{
    DataRow myRow = null;
    myRow = dtResults.NewRow();
    for (j = mdArray.GetLowerBound(1); j <= mdArray.GetUpperBound(1); ++j)
    {

        myRow[Convert.ToInt32(j)] = mdArray[i, j];      
    }
    dtResults.Rows.Add(myRow);
}
```

> **mdArray** is the multi dimentional array i am referring to.

The above codes works fine when the size or length of the array is less than 100. However, for bigger sizes, like >5000 elements, it takes me too much time to insert the data from array to the DataTable I am building on the fly since i am looping for each element.

Is there a way wherein we can convert Multi Dimentional Array directly to DataTable without doing looping to each element to maximize the performance?

Appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: hello, did you think of using LINQ ? refer to  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8932997/3963522

Comment: @AhmadMM will using LINQ improve the performance? I would have thought underneath the LINQ statement it would be doing a loop internally anyway?

Comment: In my opinion, try to change your way of parsing data into 2D-array , instead of 2D-array use a LIST<int,int> if your 2D array contains only integers or List<class you create> it'll be much easier to parse it to datatable and you can use LINQ, in addition, the operation will be fast, and efficient

Comment: @AhmadMM The 2D Array is the returned value of the External API package I'm using. Thank you.

Comment: @IanSiñel - Can you have your API return a `T[][]` rather than `T[,]`?

Comment: Hi @Enigmativity Unfortunately, not. That is an external API which I don't have control of. I am currently doing a workaround which I dump the array into excel file. By dumping it in excel, I don't have to loop over each element as I can have MyExcel.Range[rngAddress].Value = MultiDimensional array. Then after this, I will have to perform SQL select over the excel file and have the SQL results to DataTable object. I am not sure if this is the most efficient way though.

Comment: @IanSiñel - Then try having a play with `.OfType<T>()` and see if you can do this with a single enumerable.